# How to backup and restore large .sql file about 4GB in MariaDB 10.0?

Tags: database, backup, restore

I have a `.sql` file size about `4GB`. I want to restore this `database`. However `'max_allowed_packet'` option is only *1GB*. So, how to restore this database? Someone help me please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a sql file (text file). Split [this file to for example 10 parts](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=split%20text%20file%20into%20multiple%20files&oq=split%20text%20file) and execute them.